# Golang server with MYSQL and CORS: 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error when redirecting to a dashboard

Tags: mysql, database, go, credentials

I have a server written in golang. It connects to a mysql db to check if logins are valid and if they are it's supposed to redirect to the dashboard; otherwise they are supposed to reload the page. I keep getting

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/gui/dashboard.html. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed)

I've rewritten my code more times then I can count ill my functions

Go Server

```golang
func CheckCredentials(creds Credentials) (bool, error) {
    log.Println("Attempting to connect to the database")

    // Open MySQL connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to connect to the database:", err)
        return false, fmt.Errorf("failed to connect to the database: %w", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    log.Println("Checking if the username and password are valid and not expired")

    // Check if the username and password are valid and not expired
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ? AND expires_at > NOW()", creds.Username, creds.Password)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to query the database:", err)
        return false, fmt.Errorf("failed to query the database: %w", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var count int
    if rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&count)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Failed to read data from the database:", err)
            return false, fmt.Errorf("failed to read data from the database: %w", err)
        }
    }

    if count > 0 {
        return true, nil
    } else {
        return false, nil
    }
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Received request to loginHandler")

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS")

    if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
    }

    if r.Method != http.MethodPost {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid request method", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error reading request body:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to read request body", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if len(body) == 0 {
        http.Error(w, "Empty request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    var creds Credentials
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &creds)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error decoding request body:", err)
        http.Error(w, "Invalid request body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("Received credentials: %+v\n", creds)

    // Call the CheckCredentials function to perform authentication
    success, err := CheckCredentials(creds)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    if success {
        // Authentication successful
        // Respond with success message or redirect the user
        http.Redirect(w, r, "gui/dashboard.html", http.StatusFound)
    } else {
        // Authentication failed, respond with error message or redirect to login page
        http.Redirect(w, r, "gui/index.html", http.StatusFound)
    }
}
```

I was expecting it to redirect to my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cross-origin request. Let's assume the setup is:

- the web page is served at `http://localhost:8081/gui/index.html`
- the login service is served at `http://localhost:8080/login`

The following code does not work as what you. It causes **the AJAX request** be redirected to

- `http://localhost:8080/gui/dashboard.html` (or `http://localhost:8080/gui/index.html`)

But what you want is **the web page** being redirected to

- `http://localhost:8081/gui/dashboard.html` (or `http://localhost:8081/gui/index.html`)

```golang
if success {
    // Authentication successful
    // Respond with success message or redirect the user
    http.Redirect(w, r, "gui/dashboard.html", http.StatusFound)
} else {
    // Authentication failed, respond with error message or redirect to login page
    http.Redirect(w, r, "gui/index.html", http.StatusFound)
}
```

Here it should return a response to indicate whether the credential is valid, and leave the redirect logic to the client.